# How do I visualize a matrix with colors and values displayed?

Tags: matlab, matrix, data-visualization

I want to create images like this from a double precision matrix using MATLAB.

Sample image:
[image]

http://twitpic.com/2xs943

Answer (score 91, accepted):

You can create this sort of plot yourself pretty easily using the built-in functions [`imagesc`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/imagesc.html) and [`text`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/text.html) and adjusting a number of parameters for the graphics objects. Here's an example:

```
mat = rand(5);           % A 5-by-5 matrix of random values from 0 to 1
imagesc(mat);            % Create a colored plot of the matrix values
colormap(flipud(gray));  % Change the colormap to gray (so higher values are
                         %   black and lower values are white)

textStrings = num2str(mat(:), '%0.2f');       % Create strings from the matrix values
textStrings = strtrim(cellstr(textStrings));  % Remove any space padding
[x, y] = meshgrid(1:5);  % Create x and y coordinates for the strings
hStrings = text(x(:), y(:), textStrings(:), ...  % Plot the strings
                'HorizontalAlignment', 'center');
midValue = mean(get(gca, 'CLim'));  % Get the middle value of the color range
textColors = repmat(mat(:) > midValue, 1, 3);  % Choose white or black for the
                                               %   text color of the strings so
                                               %   they can be easily seen over
                                               %   the background color
set(hStrings, {'Color'}, num2cell(textColors, 2));  % Change the text colors

set(gca, 'XTick', 1:5, ...                             % Change the axes tick marks
         'XTickLabel', {'A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E'}, ...  %   and tick labels
         'YTick', 1:5, ...
         'YTickLabel', {'A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E'}, ...
         'TickLength', [0 0]);
```

And here's the figure this generates:

[image]

If you run into trouble with the x-axis tick labels you choose being too wide and overlapping one another, here's how you can handle it:

- **Newer versions of MATLAB:** Not sure which version this was added, but in newer versions axes objects now have the [properties](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/matlab.graphics.axis.axes-properties.html#property_d119e52325) `'{X|Y|Z}TickLabelRotation'`, which allow you to rotate the labels and fit them better.
- **Older versions of MATLAB:** For older versions you can find some submissions on the [MathWorks File Exchange](https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/) that can rotate the tick label text, like [XTICKLABEL_ROTATE](https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/3486-xticklabel-rotate) from [Brian Katz](https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/profile/authors/16217-brian-katz).

Comment: for a more general solution, you should compare against `mean(get(gca,'CLim'))` instead of `0.5` to determine the color of the text on a grayscale colormap background.

Comment: another remark (the last one I swear!): if the values have long and short strings (say `mat=rand(5)*1000; mat(1)=1; mat(2)=1000;`) the text will not be centered because of the spaces padded. You might want to do: `textStrings = strtrim( cellstr(textStrings) );`

Comment: @Amro: That's a good suggestion as well. I overlooked it because the first solution I posted actually created the strings directly from a cell array using CELLFUN, so there was no padding to begin with. I changed the solution to make it a little easier to read.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I will user it and find some method to rotate xtick

Comment: I wish I could do more than upvoting.

Comment: Already the *Get the middle value of the color range + Choose white or black for the text color of the strings so they can be easily seen over the background color* deserves the upvote

Comment: This is great!
One mod for Octave: I had to add `textColors = +textColors` to cast from logical to double before setting the `hStrings` colors. I guess Octave must be more picky about the data type for that setting.

Answer (score 18):

```
h = imagesc(magic(8))
impixelregion(h)
```

http://www.mathworks.com/help/toolbox/images/ref/impixelregion.html

Requires Image Processing Toolbox
[image]

Answer (score 1):

I expect you could persuade Matlab to draw that, if you look at the File Exchange you may find someone has already written the code.  But it would be a lot easier, if you don't have the code, to use MS Excel.

**EDIT:** So I gave this some more thought and here's what I came up with.  I've not mastered posting graphics to SO, so trust me, this will lead you towards a solution.  But it would honestly be easier with Excel.

First define a matrix with your data values; I call the matrix `G` in the following.  Then execute the commands:

```
image(G); 
colormap(gray)
```

Now, I had to do some fiddling around, rescaling the data, to get a good graphic, but this should produce a gray-scale plot with numeric axes.  Now, go to your figure window and open the plot tools.

Select the X axis and hit the `Ticks` button.  All you have to do now is edit the labels to the texts that you want.  Do the same for the Y axis.  Write the numbers in the squares on the plot -- use the Text Box from the Annotations menu.

After a lot of fiddling about you'll have the graphic you want.  At this point, I suggest that you choose the menu command File | Generate M-File and do just that.  If you want to create such graphics programmatically in future just turn the generated M file into a proper function that does what you want.

But it's still a lot easier in Excel.

Answer (score 1):

If you only care about looking at zero/non-zero entries in your matrix (e.g. if it's sparse), use [`spy`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/spy.html).

Else, use [`imagesc`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/imagesc.html).

PS: I can't access your image