# How do I visualize a matrix with colors and values displayed without Matlab?

Tags: visualization

I want to visualize some data matrix I have by coloring each cell of the matrix in a different gradient based on the cell values. [Someone already asked on SO how to do exactly this using Matlab.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3942892/how-do-i-visualize-a-matrix-with-colors-and-values-displayed)

I don't have access to Matlab. Is there some free tool that would allow me to do this? Or some easy way to create such an image programmatically (from python maybe or with gnuplot)?

Here is an exemple of what I would like to achieve :

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I f you already know matlab, the easier is to use [octave](http://www.gnu.org/software/octave/). it's free an the syntax is exactly same.

Comment: I don't know Matlab, but I can learn. Thanks for your answer.

Comment: You can just use the same code than the link you provided: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3942892/how-do-i-visualize-a-matrix-with-colors-and-values-displayed