# How to visualize sequentially many matrices in matlab on the same canvas to make video?

Tags: matlab, visualization

I need something like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3942892/how-do-i-visualize-a-matrix-with-colors-and-values-displayed), but I have many matrices which describe 2D electric field change in process of time. So I would like matrices visualizations replaced each other, to get video

Comment: I do not understand, how to sequentially load and visualize files with matrices with different names (for example: 1.dat ,2.dat , 3.dat , 4.dat , ...etc) on the same "canvas"

Answer (score 2):

I want to give you a sample code to generate an animated gif from a sequence of plots. You can modify the plots to generate anything you like; e.g. the one in your link.

```
gifOutputName = 'sample.gif';

%# As an example, let us draw a 3-D plot
%# You can generalize it to anything you like
Z = peaks; surf(Z);
axis tight
set(gca,'nextplot','replacechildren');
for j = 1:20
    surf(sin(2*pi*j/20)*Z,Z)

    %# Grab the current frame
    RGB = frame2im(getframe(gcf));

    %# Reduce it to 256 colors since it's gonna be GIf image
    [IND, map] = rgb2ind(RGB, 256);

    if j == 1 % Vreate in the first step

        %# 'LoopCount' indicates how many times the animation will play, 
        %# Inf states infinity. Refer to "GIF-Specific Parameters" in the 
        %# documentation.
        imwrite(IND, map, gifOutputName, 'gif', 'LoopCount', Inf);

    else %# Otherwise, append it to the previous
        imwrite(IND, map, gifOutputName, 'gif', 'WriteMode', 'append');
    end
end
close %# Close the figure
```

[image]
<sub>(source: [ismailari.com](http://ismailari.com/wp-content/uploads/2008/07/ornek_animasyon.gif))</sub>