# imagesc function in Matlab

Tags: matlab, matrix, image-scaling

I was recently looking  at the imagesc function on:

http://www.mathworks.co.uk/help/matlab/ref/imagesc.html

What I want to do is take a square matrix of anything, doesn't matter what, integers, characters etc. and produce an image of it so that I can draw over the top of it i.e. so it produces an image like this:

http://iching.egoplex.com/faq.html

Can the imagesc function do this? Because trying it so far, I have only been able to get multicoloured squares?

Edit: I tried:

```
a = ['a','b','c';'d','e','f';'g','h','i']
```

and then.

```
imagesc(a)
```

But all I got was a blank graph and:

```
{ Error using <a href="matlab:helpUtils.errorDocCallback('image')" style="font-weight:bold">image</a>
```

Error using image
Numeric or logical matrix required for image CData

Error in imagesc (line 19)
    hh = image(varargin{1},'CDataMapping','scaled');

Comment: Please see here how to use `imagesc` to produce such a graph: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3942892/how-do-i-visualize-a-matrix-with-colors-and-values-displayed

Answer (score 1):

if you use colormap(gray(256)), before imagesc it will givee you a grayscale image