# how do solve this error message? 'Error using image Numeric or logical matrix required for image CDate

Tags: image, matlab, cell-array

I have the following code:

```
tile {6} = imread ('tw.png','png');
tile {5} = imread ('twpw.png','png');
tile {4} = imread ('twpb.png','png');
tile {3} = imread ('tb.png','png');
tile {2} = imread ('tbpw.png','png');
tile {1} = imread ('tbpb.png','png');

board = zeros(8,8)

% the board image matrix is first empty (no tile )
board = [];

% we add four empty white tiles to the first row
board = [ board tile {6} tile {6} tile {6} tile {6}];

% we add four black tiles with white pawn to the second row
board = [ board ; tile {2} tile {2} tile {2} tile {2}];

figure(1);
image(board);
set (gcf ,'Position ' ,[150 150 50* c 50* r]);
```

But I get the error:

> Error using image.
>
> Numeric or logical matrix required for image CData

Why can't my board show up?

Comment: What version are you using?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20480662/imagesc-function-in-matlab

Comment: I am using MATLAB R2013a

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot have a space in the expression `tile {i}`, it should be `tile{i}`.

Otherwise it interpreted as `tile` (the entire cell array), then `{i}` (a cell array containing a scalar value), rather than indexing into the array using `tile{i}` to get the i-th cell content.

---

## EDIT:

Here is some code to illustrate:

```
% cell-array of tiles
tile{1} = zeros(5,5);    % black tile
tile{2} = ones(5,5);     % white tile
tile{3} = ones(5,5)*0.5; % gray tile

% build a 2x3 matrix of "blocks"
board = [tile{2}, tile{1}, tile{2} ;
         tile{1}, tile{3}, tile{1}];

% show as indexed image with a grayscale colormap
imagesc(board), axis image
colormap(gray(3))
h = colorbar; set(h, 'YTick',[0 0.5 1])
```

[image: tiled_image]

Comment: if i want to change the white tile into black tile? how do i access the white tile and make it into black?

Comment: i got this error Undefined function 'zero' for input
arguments of type 'double'. when i tried the 'tile{1} = zeros(5,5);'