# How to avoid displaying zero-values in confusion matrix

Tags: matlab, matlab-figure

I plotted a confusion matrix in Matlab using the code from [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3942892/how-do-i-visualize-a-matrix-with-colors-and-values-displayed).

However whenever there is a zero on the cell it is still shown. How can I eliminate the printing of `0.00`'s on the cells?

Sample of my confusion matrix

[image]

Answer (score 9, accepted):

After you removed all spaces, find `'0.00'` and substitute it with spaces again

```
idx = find(strcmp(textStrings(:), '0.00'));
textStrings(idx) = {'   '};
```

The complete code will then be:

```
mat = rand(5);           %# A 5-by-5 matrix of random values from 0 to 1
mat(3,3) = 0;            %# To illustrate
mat(5,2) = 0;            %# To illustrate
imagesc(mat);            %# Create a colored plot of the matrix values
colormap(flipud(gray));  %# Change the colormap to gray (so higher values are
                         %#   black and lower values are white)

textStrings = num2str(mat(:),'%0.2f');  %# Create strings from the matrix values
textStrings = strtrim(cellstr(textStrings));  %# Remove any space padding

%% ## New code: ###
idx = find(strcmp(textStrings(:), '0.00'));
textStrings(idx) = {'   '};
%% ################

[x,y] = meshgrid(1:5);   %# Create x and y coordinates for the strings
hStrings = text(x(:),y(:),textStrings(:),...      %# Plot the strings
                'HorizontalAlignment','center');
midValue = mean(get(gca,'CLim'));  %# Get the middle value of the color range
textColors = repmat(mat(:) > midValue,1,3);  %# Choose white or black for the
                                             %#   text color of the strings so
                                             %#   they can be easily seen over
                                             %#   the background color
set(hStrings,{'Color'},num2cell(textColors,2));  %# Change the text colors

set(gca,'XTick',1:5,...                         %# Change the axes tick marks
        'XTickLabel',{'A','B','C','D','E'},...  %#   and tick labels
        'YTick',1:5,...
        'YTickLabel',{'A','B','C','D','E'},...
        'TickLength',[0 0]);
```

This gives:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

does this work - 
do a loop over `i` and `j` (spatial dimensions) after `textStrings` is defined and before it is converted to cell, and set

```
textStrings(i,j,1:4)='    ';
```

depending on if `mat(i,j)` is really close to `0.00` using an `if-else` statement

Comment: i haven't tested it yet. that's why my answer started with "does this work" :P let me test it and comment back in 2 min :P

Comment: see for yourself `a=rand(3,1);
a
a=num2str(a,'%0.2f');
a
a(2,:)='    ';
a
a= strtrim(cellstr(a));
a

x=[1 2 3];
y=[4 5 6];

plot(x,y,'+');
hold on;
text(x(:),y(:),a(:));
xlim([0 4]);
ylim([3 7]);`

Comment: Robert P. your code works great, i should make myself familiar with `find` and `strcmp` :P

Comment: A little side note: The code you posted in the answer won't work. `textStrings(i,j,1:4) = '   ';` implies `textStrings` is a 3D matrix.

Comment: aah. my answer was more of a hint about what to do. but yes you are correct, it won't work- `num2str(mat(:))` converts a matrix to a column vector of strings. my bad :P `i` n `j` would have to be converted to a column dimension