# imagesc like feature with non-rectangular grids [MATLAB]

Tags: python, matlab

If i want to color a square grid with different color in each grid cells, then it is possible in MATLAB with a simple call to `imagesc` command like [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3942892/6557795).

What if i want to color different cells in a grid like this:
[image]

Is this functionality available by default in either python or Matlab? I tried discretizing this grid with very small square cells. And then color each cell. That works. But it seems ordinary. Is there a smarter way to get his done?

Comment: You will need to create your own custom `patch` object

Comment: Any website i can learn to do that from easily?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In python, there is the builtin `polar` projection for the `axes`. This projection allows you to automatically use almost every plotting method in polar coordinates. In particular, you need to you `pcolor` or `pcolormesh` as follows

```
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

r = np.linspace(0,4,5)
theta = np.linspace(0,2*np.pi,10)
theta,r = np.meshgrid(theta,r)
values = np.random.rand(*(theta.shape))

ax = plt.subplot(111,polar=True)
ax.pcolor(theta,r,values)
plt.show()
```

Note that this will produce a plot like this

[image: default polar pcolor behavior]

which is almost what you want. The obvious problem is that the patch vertices are joined by straight lines and not lines that follow the circle arc. You can solve this by making the angles array denser. Here is a posible way to do it.

```
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

r = np.linspace(0,4,5)
theta = np.linspace(0,2*np.pi,10)

values = np.random.rand(r.size,theta.size)

dense_theta = np.linspace(0,2*np.pi,100)
v_indeces = np.zeros_like(dense_theta,dtype=np.int)
i = -1
for j,dt in enumerate(dense_theta):
    if dt>=theta[i+1]:
        i+=1
    v_indeces[j] = i

T,R = np.meshgrid(dense_theta,r)

dense_values = np.zeros_like(T)

for i,v in enumerate(values):
    for j,ind in enumerate(v_indeces):
        dense_values[i,j] = v[ind]

ax = plt.subplot(111,polar=True)
ax.pcolor(T,R,dense_values)
plt.show()
```

Which would produce

[image: improved pcolor]

I am not aware of a way to do this in matlab but I googled around and found [this](https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/49040-pcolor-in-polar-coordinates) that says it can produce `pcolor` plots in polar coordinates. You should check it out.