# How to add values to the confusion matrix?

Tags: matlab, matlab-figure

The code is as follows:

```
g1 = [1 1 2 2 3 3]';    % Known groups
g2 = [1 1 2 3 4 5]';    % Predicted groups

[C,order] = confusionmat(g1,g2);
figure; imagesc(C);

accuracyAll = trace(C)/sum(C(:));
disp(['Total accuracy is ',num2str(accuracyAll*100),'%']);
```

When you run the code, you will get a figure. My question is 
how to add the corresponding accuracy in the blocks of the 
figure?

Comment: `C` is already a confusion matrix.  What exactly do you mean by "add the corresponding values"?

Comment: I read that as text labels in the figure @rayryeng

Comment: @LuisMendo OK that makes much more sense.  I agree with your answer below.

Comment: @rayryeng: This may be a better reference duplicate: [How do I visualize a matrix with colors and values displayed?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/3942892/52738)

Comment: @gnovice That's the one I was looking for... I was looking for literally 10 minutes on your list of posts... I had to settle with Amro's because I couldn't find it.  I'm going to reopen for you to dupehammer.

Comment: @rayryeng, i modified the question. I thought for each block there is a corresponding accuracy for it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this what you want?

```
[ii, jj, vv] = find(C);
text(jj(:), ii(:), num2str(vv(:)))
```

Comment: It did not put the exact corresponding values in each block.

Comment: Please see the C above, only 5 blocks contain values.

Comment: Do you mean you only want nonzero values? You should have specified that.

Comment: Yes, only the vaules shows in C matrix.

Comment: See edited answer

Comment: @brownwang "Only the values shows in `C` matrix" doesn't make any sense.  Each element in the matrix is a value.

Comment: @brownwang [This](http://oi64.tinypic.com/555xk2.jpg) is what I'm getting using your `C`. If it's not correct, you'll have to do a better attempt at explaining why

Comment: @LuisMendo You've done more than enough. I think this is what the OP wants even when he has poorly communicated it.

Comment: @brownwang Your question is still unclear to me. If you want to place the same number in all nonzero blocks, use something like `[ii, jj] = find(C); text(jj(:), ii(:), num2str(33))`

Comment: @brownwang Oh, come on, the number was just an example. I don't really get what you want, sorry

Comment: @brownwang that was his precious answer before you decided to complain. Your indecisiveness is intolerable.