# How do I label each (X, Y) coordinate in a plot on matlab?

Tags: matlab, plot, figure

If I have this code

```
plot(X, Y, 'rx')
```

How do I add a custom label for each of these (X, Y) coordinates which would display next to the red x on the figure?

Comment: By custom label you mean some text? If so then see https://ch.mathworks.com/help/matlab/creating_plots/add-text-to-specific-points-on-graph.html

Comment: That's the one, thank you!

Comment: [This post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3943939/52738), while not a duplicate, should still give you some idea.